# What is the mark that looks like a slur but with straight lines, not curved

Tags: notation, articulation

In "Curtain Call" by John Wasson, the oboe part (and others) includes an articulation mark that I'm not familiar with. It looks like a slur, but the up and down are straight lines, instead of curved.
[image]

Could somebody explain to me what I'm *supposed* to be doing here? I've been playing it as a bit of a bend, but I'm not convinced that's correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is called the shake!  It adds a short grace figure to the transition to the second note like this:
[image]

Always start the shake figure by holding the first note slightly. 
For a descending shake you then go up a step, back down to the first note, then to the second note. Notice in your example the second note of each shake has a teepee articulation, so honor that.

On brass the shake is done with the lip.